# How to add to use push() with a specified key instead of default key on firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Realtime Database Screenshot on Firebase]

So I'm trying to store user information in a database using Firebase, which includes their email, ID, and associated group.

Each time a new user creates an account their data is saved in the parent node `Managers`

Here is my code so far,

`var manRef =  firebase.database().ref('Managers');`

`function saveManage(sEmail, uid, society){`

`manRef.push({
        ManagerID : uid,
        Email : sEmail,
        Society : society
    })
}`

For variables in the function `saveManage` are gathered from entries on a form, I want to be able to push a new entry into the node `Managers` but have the highlighted key in the image be set as a predefined value, such as the `uid` so that it is easier for me to reference the individual entries later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to set() the value at your predefined location instead of using push(), which always uses its own algorithm for generating the key.

```
manRef.child(uid).set({
        ManagerID : uid,
        Email : sEmail,
        Society : society
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like below to make this function robust. Note, I like to `.toLowerCase()` properties before storing them. This way you can now call this same function even if you want to update only their email and leave the rest alone.

```
var managersRef =  firebase.database().ref('managers');

function saveManager(email, uid, society){
    var obj = {};
    if (uid !== undefined){
      if (email !== undefined){
        obj["email"][email.toLowerCase()];
      }
      if (society !== undefined){
        obj["society"][society.toLowerCase()];
      }
      managersref.child(uid).update(obj);
    } else {
      console.log("uid required") //or throw an error
    }
}
```